# uibutton in custom cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I confused about my custom cell. I am creating custom cell including the 2 labels and one button. Now how can I set the button click event as I am using this cell in another file ?

any suggestion ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one create the button, one need to set the action for that **(The function,which respond to the user interaction)**,

So this action will always receive the touch event for **UIButton** regardless where your are adding your `UIButton` as subview , means you can add your button as subview in any class which is inherited from `UIView`

**EDITED:**

you can either define the action ifor your `UIButton` in **CustomCell** OR in your `TableView 's` class, But the decision could be taken based on the action of your `UIButton`, if the button change the state of your `CustomCell` then add it in your `CustomCell` **and** if the button do some external operation (like sending request to server) then add it in the same class where you create the **CustomCell**.

Comment: thanks for reply... ya i know that but I am my button comes from custom cell so I want to know that where should I define the action method and how ?

Comment: @Maulik : So put it in the same class where you create the CustomCell.

Comment: ok done.. but in table's cell , my button is added with an image when I select the row and then click on the button at that time button's image is disappeared and then if i click again somewhere else on the same row then image appears.. !!! what could be wrong ?

Comment: @Maulik: I think,May be you need to add the images for different state in UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the object of that another file where you use that custom cell as a target of that button.

For Ex.

In myOtherFile.m

myCell *cell = myCell
cell.targetController = self;

In myCell.m

UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:custom];

[btn addTarget:targetController action:@selector(Action:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];